# How do I replace a column in python with a list of keywords based on which keyword the column contains?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that has many keywords like this:

keywords = ['Chinese', 'American', 'Japanese', 'Greek']

Dataframe is

### **Resteraunt  || Catagory

### McDonalds   || 'Burger,Fast Food,American'

### Sticky Rice || 'Sushi,Japanese'

### Schechuan   || 'Resteraunt, Japanese, Takeout'

### Gyro King   || 'Greek, Gyro, Food'

What I want is:

### Resteraunt  || Categories || Cuisine

### McDonalds   || 'Burger,Fast Food,American'    || "American"

### Sticky Rice || 'Sushi,Japanese'               ||"Japanese"

### Schechuan   || 'Resteraunt, Chinese, Takeout' || "Chinese"

### Gyro King   || 'Greek, Gyro, Food'            || "Greek"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to capture the `Cuisine`.

```
joined_keywords = '|'.join(keywords)

df['Cuisine']= (
                df['Catagory'].str.extract(fr'({joined_keywords})',expand=False)
                              .fillna('NotFound')
                )
```

##### # Outupt :

```
print(out)

   Resteraunt                       Catagory   Cuisine
0   McDonalds     Burger, FastFood, American  American
1  StickyRice                Sushi, Japanese  Japanese
2   Schechuan  Resteraunt, Japanese, Takeout  Japanese
3    GyroKing              Greek, Gyro, Food     Greek
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findcuisine(col):
  for word in keywords:
    if word in col:
      return word

df['Cuisine'] = df['Category'].apply(findcuisine)
```

Output

```
    Restaurant  Category                    Cuisine
0   McDonalds   Burger,Fast Food,American   American
1   Sticky Rice Sushi,Japanese              Japanese
2   Schechuan   Japanese,Takeout            Japanese
3   Gyro King   Greek, Gyro, Food           Greek
```